# have 1 button for a save and invoke JS function in cakephp

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I have a cakephp website and in the view below I have 2 buttons on a form. What I want to do is simply press on the Continue button and invoke the JS function. Currently I click the calculate button to invoke the JS function then i click continue button on this form (2 button clicks).  I just want to do have 1 button for this process.

```
   <input type="button" value="calculate" id="calculate_address_lat_long" class="btn btn-info btn-block waves-effect waves-light">

    <div class="mute" id="formated_address_lat_long"></div> 
  ...

  <?php     echo $this->Form->button(__('Continue'))

  //this didnt work
   $options = array('label' => 'Continue', 'id' => 'calculate_address_lat_long',  'onclick' => 'calculate_address_lat_long()');
                                       echo $this->Form->button($options);


  //jquery


$(document).on('click', '#calculate_address_lat_long', function () {
        var address = '';
        address += $('#street').val();
        address += ' ' + $('#suburb').val();
        address += ' ' + $('#postcode').val();
        address += ' ' + $('#state').val();

     //  alert( $('#street').val());
         alert( address);

             alert(google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK);

        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {


             //     alert('asdasd');
                  console.log(results); 
                var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                $('#lat').val(latitude);
                $('#long').val(longitude);
                $('#formated_address_lat_long')
                    .html('<div class="alert alert-success">' + results[0].formatted_address + '</div>')
                    .fadeTo(100, 0.1).fadeTo(250, 1)
                    .css({"position": "relative","top": "15px"});
           // alert($('#lat').val(latitude));

            } else {
                //  alert('qqqasdasd');

             //     alert($('#lat').val(latitude));
           // alert($('#long').val(longitude));
                $('#formated_address_lat_long')
                    .fadeTo(100, 0.1).fadeTo(250, 1)
                    .html('<div class="alert alert-error">Address Not Found</div>')
                    .css({"position": "relative","top": "15px"});
            }
        });
        // alert('1111qqqasdasd');

    });
```

Comment: There's nothing here about any JavaScript.

Comment: its  added as its just a call i need to a jquery function

Comment: So, just add it to the Continue button instead?

Comment: I couldnt add it to the Continue Button 'look in my code as i just added it. I got it wrong so thats why i am asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the HTML method, on a single page, there must be only one unique id.
in your case the HTML button id="calculate_address_lat_long" and CakePHP generate button id="calculate_address_lat_long". So, try using a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to the [button function](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-button-elements) is the title, and options are the second parameter. Try this:

```
$options = array('id' => 'calculate_address_lat_long',  'onclick' => 'calculate_address_lat_long()');
echo $this->Form->button('Continue', $options);
```

Comment: no this doesnt work. the JS function gets the lat/long but it never gets saved .  Its out of sync as the lat/long needs to be found first from JS function and then passed to the controller to save.

Comment: Your click handler isn't explicitly stopping the propagation of the event, so it should proceed on to submitting the form after this runs. Is the function itself generating any errors in the browser console? That would halt the JS execution, preventing form submission. Is there any network traffic happening, perhaps it's going to the wrong URL or not sending the correct data and that's why it doesn't save?

Comment: Hi it wasnt working in syn like the JS then the form being submitted. It was a bad solution anyway as you might as well do it server side as my answer

Answer (score 0):

I need to write the code in php in the controller and do it server side

```
  if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
            $data = $this->request->data;
          $address=$data['address_street'] .'+'. $data['address_suburb'] .'+'. $data['address_postcode'] .'+'. $data['address_state'] ;
          $address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address);


              $json = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$address.'&key=mykey");

             $json = json_decode($json);
             $lat='';
             $long='';   

            if ($json->{'results'}!=null){
             $lat = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lat'};
             $long = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lng'};
            //   debug($lat);
            //  debug($long); 
            }
```